# Keep Action in MainActitivity when open a new view like Toast

Tags: android

Like Toast, show in the Screen but Activity still remain in MainActivity

my GoogleMAP have some POIs (Point of Interest) in the Map
When i click in the POI, it will show the view or new notification

But i want to have ability of clicking another POI to have new view and close the view of POI previous

Thanks all,

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Are you have OnTouch event troubles or UI problems ? or POI obtaining problems ?

Comment: my problem is not still focus on MainActivity(GoogleMAP) after it show the View(Canvas to make a View). As you know, With Toast we can keep Focus(Activity) on GoogleMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static final Toast instance and on the location at where you are showing the toast first call cancel on toast instance in try...catch block and then show in another try catch.